# Convert C# DateTime to C++ std::chrono::system_clock::time_point

Tags: c#, c++, datetime

I need, in a C++/CLR code, convert a `DateTime` that is coming from C# to a C++ `std::chrono::system_clock:time_point` equivalent.

Will that code do the job os is there a better way to do it ?

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point ConvertDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(dateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point ret = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(unixTimestamp );

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think your code works, though I don't have `DateTime` available to test (I'm not on Windows).  `UtcNow` is a "static" function that returns the current expressed as "the current UTC time", which likely means:  time duration past 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  I believe your formulation is independent of the value of your parameter `dateTime`.

I recommend trafficking in terms of `DateTime.Ticks` which is the number of 100-nanosecond ticks past 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC where UTC is defined proleptically.

Using this [free, open source, header-only library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), you can easily find the difference between the `DateTime` epoch and the `system_clock` epoch in terms of the 100-nanosecond ticks that VS uses:

It is first convenient to define `ticks` as 100-nanoseconds units:

```
using ticks = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t,
                 std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<100>, std::nano>>;
```

And then `ConvertDateTime` can be written:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
ConvertDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return system_clock::time_point{ticks{dateTime.Ticks}
                - (sys_days{1970_y/jan/1} - sys_days{0001_y/jan/1})};
}
```

If you really dislike the idea of using [this date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), then you can hard code a magic constant in the above function like so:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
ConvertDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return system_clock::time_point{ticks{dateTime.Ticks - 621355968000000000}};
}
```

Either one of these gets you a `system_clock::time_point` with the exact same precision as the `DateTime` (on VS).